# AudioPlayer Vue3: #The operation is not supported // Chrome works on Laptop, but not Safari and neither of them on iPhone (but they all work in DEV)

Tags: nginx, flask, vuejs3, gunicorn, audio-player

I am facing a miracle and I was wondering if somebody understands what is going on here.
The below code in my Vite/Vue3 application shows a "play" button, and I observe this inconsistent behavior:

When running on my development machine (backend + frontend on same server)

- On Laptop: Chrome can play the music
- On Laptop: Safari can play the music
- On iPhone: Chrome can play the music
- On iPhone: Safari can play the music

When running on my production machine (backend + frontend on same server, in a docker container)

- On Laptop: Chrome can play the music
- On Laptop: Safari cannot play the music and spits out the below error message into the console
- On iPhone: Neither Chrome nor Safari can play it

The queries open the exact same page at the exact same time, and the backend is definitely up and running.

On Prod, Safari on Laptop, Safari + Chrome on iPhone in PROD would show the following message on the UI:

> The operation is not supported.

My hunch is that something with my server setup in PROD / nginx is flawed, and Chrome is more forgiving with me than Safari and thus works, while Safari fails.

I can't make sense of the error message, and would appreciate any pointer that helps me resolve this.

Thank you all for your time.

PS: The socket.io bit in the nginx is probably not relevant, but I pasted it in anyways so it shows the complete configuration. The m4a file is served via the REST API, not via socket.io

PS2: The backend is a gunicorn / flask server, and happy to paste the details if that is helpful for the analysis

PS3: When I write "DEV" above, I mean the UI running with "yarn vite" as opposed to nginx serving it after building it (yarn build); which I do via a docker container.

**Vue Component:**

```
<template>
  <div v-for="index in 1" :key="index" >
    <audio-player
      preload="none"  
      :audio-list="['./api/soundfiles?path=/&filename=test-sound.m4a']"
      :show-prev-button="false" :show-next-button="false"  :show-volume-button="false" :show-playback-rate="false" :show-play-loading="false"
      @error="handleAudioError"
    /> 
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  // @ts-ignore
  import AudioPlayer from '@liripeng/vue-audio-player' 
  export default {
    methods: { 
      handleAudioError(error: any) {
        console.error(error);
          // Check the error code
        if (error.target.error) {
          console.error('Error code:', error.target.error.code);
        }
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

**nginx Configuration:**

```
server {
    listen 7331;
    root   /app/nginx/static;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Origin "";
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Origin "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # Specific WebSocket configurations
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

**Error in Safari (built)**

```
[Error] Event {isTrusted: true, _vts: 1703011892384, type: "error", target: <audio class="audio-player__audio">, currentTarget: <audio class="audio-player__audio">, …}
    handleAudioError (test3-jSNTJD8p.js:1:144)
    handleAudioError
    mt (index-6Y2yy0e4.js:1:12821)
    $e (index-6Y2yy0e4.js:1:12900)
    n (index-6Y2yy0e4.js:1:59953)

[Error] Error code: – 4
    handleAudioError (test3-jSNTJD8p.js:1:177)
    handleAudioError
    mt (index-6Y2yy0e4.js:1:12821)
    $e (index-6Y2yy0e4.js:1:12900)
    n (index-6Y2yy0e4.js:1:59953)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_set_header Origin "";
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'audio/mpeg'; # <<<<< Needed to add this to make it work with Safari/Chrome on iOS & Safari on OSX
}
```